# Sqllite: How to optimize the following query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to compute for every good in my table the number of distinct adoptions that occurred every week and by distinct adoptions I mean the number of adopters that adopted the good for the first time. I wrote this verbose code and I'm sure it can be rewritten better. Thanks.

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect("prova.db")
    conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS adoptions
                   (good TEXT  NOT NULL,
                   adopter TEXT NOT NULL,
                   slot      INTEGER NOT NULL,
                   quantity  INTEGER
                   );""")


    conn = sqlite3.connect("prova.db")
    conn.execute("""INSERT into adoptions (good, adopter, slot, quantity) VALUES ('%s', '%s', %d, %d)""" %
                 (0, 4, 0, 9))
    conn.execute("""INSERT into adoptions (good, adopter, slot, quantity) VALUES ('%s', '%s', %d, %d)""" %
                 (0, 5, 0, 10))
    conn.execute("""INSERT into adoptions (good, adopter, slot, quantity) VALUES ('%s', '%s', %d, %d)""" %
                 (0, 4, 1, 2))
    conn.commit()
    conn.execute('CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS good_idx on adoptions(good)')
    conn.execute('CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS adopter_idx on adoptions(adopter)')
    conn.execute('CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS slot_idx on adoptions(slot)')
    conn.close()

    conn = sqlite3.connect("prova.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT distinct good from adoptions""")
    goods = cur.fetchall()

    training_set_start_edge = 0
    training_set_end_edge = 1

    for good in goods:
        good = good[0]

        conn = sqlite3.connect("prova.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("""SELECT distinct adopter from adoptions 
                           where (good='%s' AND slot >=  '%d' AND slot <= '%d') 
                          """ % (good, training_set_start_edge, training_set_end_edge))
        adopters = cur.fetchall()

        print(adopters)


        for ad in adopters:
            ad = ad[0]

            conn = sqlite3.connect("prova.db")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("""SELECT min(slot) from adoptions 
                                 where (good='%s' AND adopter = '%s' AND slot >=  '%d' AND slot <= '%d') 
                                """ % (good, ad, training_set_start_edge, training_set_end_edge))
            ad_min_slot = cur.fetchall()
            ad_min_slot = ad_min_slot[0]
```

Comment: Is something like this `SELECT good, adopter, min(slot) FROM adoptions WHERE slot >= 0 AND slot <= 1 GROUP BY good, adopter` enough ?

Comment: "Optimize" as in shorter, simpler code, or in relation to execution performance?

Comment: Optimize in both if possible. GROUP BY gives me distinct adopters overall weeks for every good?

Comment: Why do you open 5 different connections to the same database?

Answer (score 0):

Your code just finds min(slot) for each couple (good, adopter).

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("prova.db")
conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS adoptions
               (good TEXT  NOT NULL,
               adopter TEXT NOT NULL,
               slot      INTEGER NOT NULL,
               quantity  INTEGER
               );""")

conn.execute("""INSERT into adoptions (good, adopter, slot, quantity) VALUES ('%s', '%s', %d, %d)""" %
             (0, 4, 0, 9))
conn.execute("""INSERT into adoptions (good, adopter, slot, quantity) VALUES ('%s', '%s', %d, %d)""" %
             (0, 5, 0, 10))
conn.execute("""INSERT into adoptions (good, adopter, slot, quantity) VALUES ('%s', '%s', %d, %d)""" %
             (0, 4, 1, 2))
conn.commit()
conn.execute('CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS good_idx on adoptions(good)')
conn.execute('CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS adopter_idx on adoptions(adopter)')
conn.execute('CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS slot_idx on adoptions(slot)')

cur = conn.cursor()

training_set_start_edge = 0
training_set_end_edge = 1

cur.execute("""
    SELECT good, adopter, min(slot) from adoptions
    where (slot >=  '%d' AND slot <= '%d')""" % (training_set_start_edge, training_set_end_edge))
```